# Transition positioning

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have some code that I would like to integrate into the a website and have it be in the middle of the screen. This code does some fading with Javascript. But I can't move it around the screen like I would like to. When I move it around it messes up the animation.

Here is the HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

jQuery fade-ins with a JavaScript for() loop

```
    <div id="elem0" class="toBeFaded">Here's the first message...</div>
    <div id="elem1" class="toBeFaded">We have second one here...</div>
    <div id="elem2" class="toBeFaded">And here's the third message...</div>
    <div id="elem3" class="toBeFaded">OMG!!! Here's the fourth message!</div>

<script src="js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>

<script src="js/fadeCode.js" defer="defer"></script>
```

​

Javascript

> $(function (){
>
> ```
> var yourFade = 1, // the amount of time in seconds that the elements will fade in AND fade out
>     yourDelay = 2, // the amount of time in seconds that there will be a delay between the fade ins and fade outs
>     fadeTime = yourFade * 1000, //convert fade seconds to milliseconds (1000)
>     delayTime = yourDelay * 1000, // convert delay seconds to milliseconds (2000)
>     totalTime = fadeTime + delayTime, //3000 milliseconds...needed for all those delays we talked about
>     allElems, // find out exactly how many page elements have the 'toBeFaded' class (4)
>     elemNoFade, // Will help us find the last element represent the last element (3)
>     i,
>     fadingElem;
>
> for (i = 0, allElems = $('.toBeFaded').length, elemNoFade = allElems - 1; i < allElems; i+=1) {
>     fadingElem = "#elem" + i;
>     if (i === 0) {
>         $(fadingElem).fadeIn(fadeTime).delay(delayTime).fadeOut(fadeTime);
>     } else if (i === elemNoFade) {
>         $(fadingElem).delay(totalTime * i).fadeIn(fadeTime);
>     } else {
>         $(fadingElem).delay(totalTime * i).fadeIn(fadeTime).delay(delayTime).fadeOut(fadeTime);
>     }
> } });​
> ```

and CSS

```
.toBeFaded {
display: none;
position:absolute;
font-size:70pt;
```

}​

and a [link](http://jsfiddle.net/kaidez/6xfKN/33/) to jsfiddle

Comment: Are CSS3 animations an option?

Comment: No I would drather do it this way

Comment: Okay. Can you put some code on jsFiddle that `moves it around`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure I see the problem. Take a look at this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/joplomacedo/6xfKN/375/

Comment: Thats great ... I ended up asking the wrong question ... and I can ask this in another question if you want but I would like it to continue rotating through do you know how to do that ?

Comment: Rotating through the animation?

Comment: `Rotating through` -- I assume starting from the beginning when it reaches the end?

Comment: Yeah, I can make another question

Comment: Here's how I did it using the code you already had: http://jsfiddle.net/joplomacedo/6xfKN/377/

Comment: The third element fades all the way out before the forth, and sometimes a random element will fade straight to the next, with about a 1/5s gap. The longer you leave it, the more weird it goes... It just said `Here's the first message...` then faded ***straight*** to `OMG!!! Here's the fourth message!`!

Comment: Didn't notice. Tbh, was in a bit of a hurry, didn't go through your code as I should have. Give me a second.